# VBA runs fine upon button click, but throws error in the end

Tags: excel, vba

I have a complex VBA function that makes lots of calculations, opens a template and inserts numbers and charts, all in perfect formatting.

The function can be represented as:

```
Function Simular()
    Dim wbout As Workbook
    Set wbout = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\out.xltx")

    ' lots of processing and outputting

    Set Simular = wbout
End Function
```

The spreadsheet has a button that calls `Simular()`.

I'm astounded that, sometimes, when all processing is done, I get the famous dialog:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I tried debugging with breakpoints. The error never shows up -- well, except when I press `F8` on the `End Function` line, which baffles me.

What could be wrong?

Comment: What type of button are you using?  (ActiveX or Form?)  And what version of Excel?  (I'm using Excel 2016 and don't get an error with either type.)

Comment: @YowE3K It's a Form button in Excel 2016, though I think I get this behavior since two years ago, hence Excel 2013 must do the same. Note that functions don't appear in "Assign Macro" dialog, you must type their names manually.

Comment: @YowE3K I created a minimal example `.xlsm`, if you'll download it: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Y2QotABWh_UF9FaTRwMExXOXc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the button I used called a `Function` directly. It seems this is inappropriate and buttons should only call `Sub`s.

I did some tests and it seems behavior when calling a `Function` from a button varies (from other "places" too). This is the code I used:

```
Function AsVariantNoSet()
End Function

Function AsVariantSet() ' This represents my original case
    Set AsVariantSet = ThisWorkbook
End Function

Function AsChartNoSet() As Chart
End Function

Function AsChartSetWorkbook() As Chart
    Set AsChartSetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
End Function
```

This is the result:

```
                    From Button     From Code
                    -----------     ---------
AsVariantNoSet()    no error        no error
AsVariantSet()      error A         no error
AsObjectNoSet()     error B         no error
AsObjectSet()       error A         no error
AsObjectSetWrong()  error C         error C

error key:
    A: Object doesn't support this property or method [OK/Help]
    B: System Error &H80070057 (-2147024809). The parameter is incorrect. [OK/Help]
    C: Run-time error '13': Type mismatch [End/Debug/Help]
```

Comment: How did you get a button to call a function directly? It makes sense that it throws an error, the function is returning an object that a button can't contain?

Comment: @jamheadart Type the function name directly in the "Assign Macro" dialog. I don't think it makes much sense, since return values can be simply discarded, like when you call a function with `Call Foo`.

Comment: I see after running some tests that you're right! I've always assumed a function that "sets" something had to be dealt with (I have no idea where I got this idea) so strings and booleans are fine to discard but anything that gets "set" is an issue. I think you've discovered a reason why I can say this is true now :D sorto of ... because I can't recreate any of the errors above (using 2010).

Comment: @jamheadart Thanks, your comment amused me a bit :) Your curiosity is refreshing. Well, looks like you're not the only one who can't recreate the issue (see comments in the question). I created a minimal `.xlsm` example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Y2QotABWh_UF9FaTRwMExXOXc

Comment: Well strange. I got the error on your file... I checked for any differences.. references... Everything was set up the same, except my function was on the SHEET and yours was in a MODULE. I swapped my function to the module and now I get the error!

Comment: I wish I knew more about how the objects to be discarded are dealt with... if function ends and created object is bounced to the same source then ok, but if function ends and the object is pushed to different source to be discarded then Error!?

Comment: The issue is not to do with returning an object, it is to do with returning certain **types** of objects.  If the function returns a `Range` object, for instance, you will not get an error.